# How to float thumbs in left and bottom of image

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

ASP .NET MVC3 shopping cart uses Bootstrap 3. 
Product page contains main image and variable number of thumbnails.
Thumbnail appear in single row

If there are many thumbnails, big white are appears in right of them.

How to enhance this layout ?

How to float thumbs over left side and bottom of main image in shopping cart.

I tried

```
<div class="detail-thumbs">
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/5056">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/5057">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/5058">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/7215">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/7217">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/7218">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/7219">
            </a>
<a>
                <img src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/7220">
            </a>
        </div>

<a class="details-picture fbox" href="/store/Store/Lightbox?product=ATH-M50X">
        <img alt="" id="detail-mainimage" src="/store/StoreImage/DetailImage/5057">
    </a>
```

How to force images to appear in bottom of main image if there are more images than main image height ?

Can some custome styles bootstrap 3, some custome mvc 3 razor view, jquery, jquery ui or some plugin used for this ? 
Which is best way ?

styles used:

```
.detail-thumbs {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

    .detail-thumbs a {
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border: thin ridge #BBBBBB;
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .detail-thumbs a img {
            height: auto;
            max-height: 47px;
            max-width: 47px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: auto;
            border: none;
        }

.details-picture {
    border: thin ridge #bbb; 
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 20px 15px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 198px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple Try this

```css
.gallery {
  width: 420px;
}
.gallery .bigimg {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#" class="bigimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
  </a><a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
  </a><a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100"/>
</div>
```